# exception: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

A have 2 models

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }

    public LibraryType Type { get; set; }

    public List<int> PubHouses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PublicHouse> PublicHouses { get; set; }

}

 public class PublicHouse
{
    [Key]
    public int PublicHouseId { get; set; }

    public string PublicHouseName { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using a Generic repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity Get(int id);
    void Create(TEntity item);
    void Update(TEntity item);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Func<TEntity, Boolean> predicate);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Dispose();
}
```

and 2 repositories:

BookRepository

```
public class BookRepository : IGenericRepository<Book>
{
    private LibraryContext _databaseLibraryContext;

    public BookRepository(string connection)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext = new LibraryContext(connection);
    }

    public void Create(Book book)
    {

        _databaseLibraryContext.Books.Add(book);
        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.Books.Remove(_databaseLibraryContext.Books.Find(id));
        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> Find(Func<Book, bool> predicate)
    {
        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.Books.Where(predicate).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public Book Get(int id)
    {
        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.Books.Find(id);
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Book> GetAll()
    {
        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.Books;
        return result;
    }

    public void Update(Book book)
    {
        var bookForUpdate = _databaseLibraryContext.Books.Where(x => x.BookId == book.BookId).FirstOrDefault();
        bookForUpdate.Name = book.Name;
        bookForUpdate.AuthorName = book.AuthorName;
        bookForUpdate.YearOfPublishing = book.YearOfPublishing;
        bookForUpdate.Type = book.Type;

        bookForUpdate.PublicHouses = book.PublicHouses;

        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.Dispose();
    }
}

public class PublicHouseRepository : IGenericRepository<PublicHouse>
{
    private LibraryContext _databaseLibraryContext;

    public PublicHouseRepository(string connection)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext = new LibraryContext(connection);
    }

    public void Create(PublicHouse publicHouse)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.Add(publicHouse);
        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }


    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.Remove(_databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.Find(id));
        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }


    public IEnumerable<PublicHouse> Find(Func<PublicHouse, bool> predicate)
    {
        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.Where(predicate).ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public PublicHouse Get(int id)
    {
        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.Find(id);
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<PublicHouse> GetAll()
    {

        var result = _databaseLibraryContext.PublicHouses.ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public void Update(PublicHouse publicHouse)
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.Entry(publicHouse).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _databaseLibraryContext.SaveChanges();
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        _databaseLibraryContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

and BookServise:

```
public class BookService
{
    private BookRepository _bookRepository;
    private PublicHouseRepository _publicHouseRepository; //

    public BookService(string connection)
    {
        _bookRepository = new BookRepository(connection);
        _publicHouseRepository = new PublicHouseRepository(connection); //
    }

    public IEnumerable<BookViewModel> GetAll()
    {
        List<Book> books = _bookRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        var result = Mapper.Map<List<Book>, List<BookViewModel>>(books);
        return result;
    }

    public BookViewModel Get(int? id)
    {
        Book book = _bookRepository.Get(id.Value);
        var result = Mapper.Map<Book, BookViewModel>(book);
        return result;
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _bookRepository.Delete(id);
    }


    public void Create(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
    {
        var book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(bookViewModel);
        book.Type = LibraryType.Books;
        IEnumerable<PublicHouse> publicHouses = _publicHouseRepository.GetAll();

        book.PublicHouses = publicHouses.Where(p => bookViewModel.PubHouses.Contains(p.PublicHouseId)).ToList();
        _bookRepository.Create(book);
    }

    public void Update(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
    {
        var book = Mapper.Map<BookViewModel, Book>(bookViewModel);

        IEnumerable<Book> books = _bookRepository.GetAll();

        int id = book.BookId;
        var bookFromDatabase = books.Where(u => u.BookId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<PublicHouse> publicHouses = _publicHouseRepository.GetAll(); //
        //book.PublicHouseName = publicHouses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PublicHouseId == book.PublicHouseId)?.PublicHouseName; //

        book.Type = LibraryType.Books;

        _bookRepository.Update(book);
    }
}
```

When I'm adding the book I have an exception:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker in BookRepository

Comment: You cannot use different contexts in your repositories and then expect them to work together. Instead of passing connection string to constructor of repositories - pass `LibraryContext` there (the same instance for both repositories). Or just don't use generic repositories at all.